# Does the $U(1)$ charge of a scalar particle flip under charge conjugation?

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-field-theory, electric-current, charge-conjugation

Consider a complex scalar particle $\phi$ coupled to an electromagnetic field. The Lagrangian is given by

$$ \mathcal{L} =(D_\mu \phi)^* D^\mu \phi - m^2 \phi^2 - \frac{1}{4} F_{\mu \nu} F^{\mu \nu}$$

where $D_\mu  = \partial_\mu - ie A_\mu $ and $F_{\mu \nu} = \partial_\mu A_\nu - \partial_\nu A_\mu$. This Lagrangian has global $U(1)$ symmetry under $\phi \rightarrow e^{i \alpha} \phi$, $\phi^* \rightarrow e^{-i\alpha } \phi$. The corresponding Noether current is given by

$$ j^\mu(\phi) = -i[\phi^* D^\mu \phi - (D^\mu \phi)^* \phi] = -i(\phi^* \partial_\mu \phi -\phi \partial_\mu \phi^* - 2ieA_\mu|\phi|^2)$$

and is interpreted as the electric current, as discussed in [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/48305/noethers-first-theorem-and-classical-proof-of-electric-charge-conservation)

One would expect that under charge conjugation $\phi \rightarrow \phi^*$ that the electric current would change sign. If I replace $\phi $ with $\phi^*$ in the current above, I find

$$j^\mu(\phi^*)= -i(\phi  \partial_\mu \phi^*-\phi^* \partial_\mu \phi - 2ie A_\mu |\phi|^2) \neq -j^\mu(\phi) $$

So it hasn't flipped sign due to the $|\phi|^2$ term. What is going on?

Answer (score 4):

Note that charge conjugation flips the sign of the vector potential $A_\mu$. You know this even from freshman physics: the potential of a positive charge is positive, while the potential of a negative charge is negative.

Comment: This argument seems circular to me. Suppose I didn’t know that complex conjugation was charge conjugation, then what would be telling me that $A_\mu$ flips sign for this transformation? As the current $j^\mu$ is the source of the EM field by the equations of motion, I would expect the following logic. Complex conjugation => the sign of $j^\mu$ flips => the sign of $A_\mu$ flips. The essence of my question is I am trying to show that complex conjugation IS charge conjugation by showing the current flips sign, but flipping $A_\mu$ by hand is assuming the current flips sign which is circular?

Comment: @Hermitian_hermit (loving your username!) which theory are you considering here? Is it the theory of a complex scalar field in an external electromagnetic field, or is it the interacting theory of electromagnetism + the complex scalar?

Comment: @Prof.Legolasov (Thank you, likewise!) I am assuming an interacting theory here because I am assuming that both the EM field and scalar field are dynamical as they both contain their own dynamical terms in the Lagrangian.

Comment: @Hermitian_hermit So I guess the real issue is, what _is_ charge conjugation? What is the _true_, _original_, _primal_, _metaphysically valid_, _proper_, _rigorous_, _legitimate_ definition of charge conjugation, right?

Comment: @Hermitian_hermit But actually that's kind of a slippery question. It's better to say that there exist certain symmetries of the Lagrangian, regardless of what we call them. Then we decide to call the one that involves a lot of complex conjugations, but doesn't involve changing, e.g. momenta and spins, "charge conjugation". For more on this see [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/428604/what-are-the-assumptions-that-c-p-and-t-must-satisfy/429516#429516).

Comment: @Hermitian_hermit Indeed, suppose you had a theory with a discrete symmetry where $A_\mu$ _didn't_ flip, but did involve complex conjugations on the complex variables. We wouldn't say, "aha, we've proven that charge conjugation doesn't _truly_ flip $A_\mu$". We would say "huh, there's a funny discrete symmetry in this theory. It looks similar to what we would call charge conjugation in other contexts, but it doesn't flip $A_\mu$."

Comment: Suppose I downgraded $A_\mu$ to a background field. The Lagrangian is $\mathcal{L} = (D_\mu \phi)^* D^\mu \phi $. This has global $U(1)$ symmetry with the same current as above. However, as the vector potential is fixed, the Lagrangian does not have the symmetry $(\phi, A_\mu) \rightarrow (\phi^*, -A_\mu)$, but instead $(\phi,e) \rightarrow (\phi^*, -e)$ and this does indeed flip the current. So if we are working with a dynamical $A_\mu$ charge conjugation must flip $A_\mu$ too as the particles are the source, while for a background $A_\mu$ charge conjugation must flip $e$?

Comment: @Hermitian_hermit If you use a fixed background field and insist that it _doesn't_ change under symmetry operations, you've broken the original symmetry, so it doesn't apply anymore.

Comment: @Hermitian_hermit Here's another example from freshman physics. Newtonian gravity has translational symmetry. But now suppose I treat the gravitational potential of the Earth as a fixed background. Then near the surface of the Earth, $\phi(\mathbf{x}) = g z$, which is no longer symmetric under translations along $z$! What is going on? By insisting I keep the Earth's field fixed (i.e. translating everything except for the Earth) I threw out the original symmetry.

Comment: @Hermitian_hermit To get the original symmetry back, I could allow the Earth to be translated too, so $\phi(\mathbf{x}) = gz \to g(z - \delta z)$. But then have I not "illegally" changed a "fixed" "background" field? Again, you can see how we're going in circles here. If you don't let yourself change some things, you have less symmetries. If you do change them, you have more symmetries. What is the "correct" choice? Whatever is most convenient for you at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

To identify which (if any) transformation should be called "charge conjugation," follow this process:

1. List the theory's discrete symmetries,
2. Discard the ones that affect spacetime (like parity and time-reversal),
3. If the ones that remain include one that has the same effect on the lagrangian as flipping the sign of the charge, then that one deserves to be called charge conjugation.

The transformation $\phi\to\phi^*$ is not a symmetry of the theory shown in the question, because it doesn't preserve the kinetic term: 
$$
 (D_\mu^*\phi)(D^\mu\phi^*)\neq (D_\mu\phi)^*(D^\mu\phi).
$$
To preserve the kinetic term, you also need to flip $A\to-A$, as indicated in knzhou's answer: the transformation $(\phi,A)\to (\phi^*,-A)$ is a symmetry.